# Significance of Power automate

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, power-automate, microsoft365

My understanding regarding the power of Microsoft's power automate is its predefined connectors that helps us to connect with multiple Microsoft as well as third party applications like github etc.,  its ability to provide nested condition control (relatable to if...else, switch) and that it provides a count of 500 actions that could be performed in a single workflow.

On the other hand , power automate's premium features seems to available only on subscription(eg., if we want to integrate with SQL server),however its basic version includes integration with only Microsoft's applications.

I would like to know whether it is a wise decision to migrate the current workflows in an existing application to Power automate in general(the upsides and downsides of it)

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: What kind of work flows you have in your existing apps? What is the technology stack of your current apps? And what are your targeted tech stack of your integrations? - all of these will determine your final decision. Can you elaborate on your as-is vs to-be state?

Comment: Workflows for processing documents, and applications are written in java. I would like to know about the functional information of power automate, any other significant feature which makes it powerful in general.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very open ended. Power automate supports automation/ integration of various kind of applications. Power automate is a low-code platform to build and integrate with multiple system easily. It is a SaaS offering of Microsoft with very good SLA. Because of it's intuitive lowcode nature and Microsoft Azure's SLA it makes it powerful.  If you want to know the ROI of your power platform implementation, then check this ROI calculator https://info.microsoft.com/ww-Landing-ROI-calculator-for-Forrester-TI-for-Power-Platform.html?LCID=EN-US. However, Power Automate has a process advisor using which you can assess your current system and it's automation opportunity using this advisor https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/process-advisor/

Answer (score 0):

As the previous writer mentioned, this is a very open-ended question so I can only speak from my own experience of when it has made sense for me to migrate something to Microsoft Power Automate rather than leave it somewhere else.

- If I had written something but actually wished that it had integrated with other apps that are connectors in Power Automate, I'd consider migrating because it can be faster rather than figuring out all of the different ways the apps talk to each other with APIs
- If I am working with someone else who may need to maintain or configure something in it that is not as much of a developer, Power Automate can be a good option because then they are configuring rather than having to look in code
- Microsoft Power Automate is easy to use and maintain, but it is not always the most performant. Writing actual code does provide more abilities to optimize, but Power Automate is a great first step. I use it for POCs quite a bit. It also has a sibling called Azure Logic Apps which uses the same connectors but is meant to run as a service on Azure.
- Cost can also be a factor. You are paying for convenience. Having stuff in code is cheaper from an operating costs perspective, but might have more maintenance in the long run, so its a decision you need to make.

I am sure there are more thoughts, but those are my preliminary ones.